# how to change user in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I have created a user name=jeffrey, password=mypass in mysql workbench using the syntax:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Now how can I connect/login this user (jeffrey)???

Comment: unless you've `GRANT`ed that user from privileges, it'll be a pretty useless login.

Comment: I know but I just want to know how to login

Comment: log in to what? mysql? or phpmyadmin?

Comment: I think the question is: with which user does MySQL workbench login. It seems to be 'root' for me. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the following steps:
1. While in MySQL Workbench click on 
**View -> Home**

2. Then click on the plus sign(**+**) besides MySQL Connections you will see a window to setup a new connection.
   You can give any name as the connections name, 
   provide the **Username:**(*In your case it will be jeffrey*)
   then **Password:** click on Store in vault... (Make sure you provide the correct password).

Click on **Test Connection** to test if the connection is successfully established.

Once successfully message appears you will see a new options tab with the connection name you just mentioned - click on it to connect. [How to verify with which user you are logged into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TPo5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/images/wb-navigator-users-privileges-login.png

Or just follow this instructions: http://blogs.technicise.com/change-root-password-in-mysql-workbench/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login to MySQL then use the below command in your respective command prompt

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=jeffrey --password=mypass mydb
```

For more information see [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connecting.html)